# How do i add items to the list?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class EditorWindowTester : EditorWindow
{
    private static readonly Vector2Int size = new Vector2Int(500, 500);
    public List<string> strings = new List<string>();

    private SerializedObject so;
    private SerializedProperty stringsProp;

    [MenuItem("Editor Test/Strings")]
    public static void Init()
    {
        EditorWindow window = GetWindow<EditorWindowTester>();
        window.minSize = size;
        window.maxSize = size;
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(stringsProp, true);
        so.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        so = new SerializedObject(this);
        stringsProp = so.FindProperty("strings");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            strings.Add(Random.Range(1, 10).ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this inside OnEnable and also inside OnGUI in both places the list stay empty.
I want to fill the list with random strings items. so there will be 10 items in the list in each item a random string of letters.

I tried the for loop inside the OnEnable and OnGUI but the list is empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    strings.Add(new Random().Next(1, 10).ToString());
}
```

Random().Next(Int32, Int32) - [Returns a random integer that is within a specified range.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-8.0)

Answer (score 0):

To add items to the list "strings", you can move the for loop that initializes the list inside the OnEnable() method, just like in the original code you posted.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    { 
        string randomString = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            randomString += (char)Random.Range('a', 'z' + 1);
        }
 
        strings.Add(randomString);
    }
```

Comment: If this solution doesn't work for you, give me a heads up with some more info on why, and I'll give a try to help you out.